# My checkboxlist doesn't align horizontally properly

Tags: c#, webforms, checkboxlist

Mine checkboxlist is very ugly. the Box doesn't align properly. See the screenshot.

Comment: can you post the HTML code which you have used ?

Comment: @Jordjmax Increase the width, and make sure the text display in single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to mention that your checkbox list will be stick to the **Width="195px"**. 
So suggestion from my side is either increase the width as per your design or remove it as mentioned below :

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="cblType" 
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="cblType_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" 
                        RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <Items>
        <asp:ListItem Text="IPP Stories" Value="IPP Stories"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="OutReach Activities " Value="OutReach Activities"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="CCA" Value="CCA"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Community Work" Value="Community Work"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Competition" Value="Competition"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Overseas Experience" Value="Overseas Experience"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="FYPJ" Value="FYPJ"></asp:ListItem>
    </Items>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

**Suggestion :**

If I am facing this situation then I would make it in two rows by adding **RepeatColumns="3"** or **RepeatColumns="4"** in CheckboxList property.

Comment: have you removed width ? and make sure that parent element of the checkboxlist is having width 100%

Comment: Oh looks like because words too long . @SpiderCode

Comment: there is a problem with your design alignment. Either change the design to fit it properly, or change the texts of List item, like OutReach Activities to **O/r Activities**, Community Work to **Comm Work**, Overseas experience to **Overseas Exp.**

Comment: Update texts as mentioned in above comment and check

Comment: check my suggestion as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to specify any width here, try not to and perhaps it will do the job. If not, please post the pertinent css style (if any)...

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="cblType" 
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="cblType_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" 
                    RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
```